# Value incremented when Scroll to bottom of listview?

Tags: android, listview, networking

I have a listview in which when I scroll to bottom of listview a progress bar is visible to user and send server request in that request I send count value ,But problem is that when I fast scroll bottom and up this count value will be incremented every time when I scroll bottom before getting response from server sending another request to server.

```
@Override
public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
    if (scrollState == AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE && bBottomOfView) {
        Log.i("Listview", "scrolling stopped...");
        if (NetworkUtil.isConnected(getActivity())) {
            sz_RecordCount = String.valueOf(m_n_DefaultRecordCount);// convert int value to string
            sz_LastCount = String.valueOf(CLastCountData.getInstance().getS_szLastCount());// convert int value to string /////

            Log.e(TAG, "Last Count::" + sz_LastCount);
            Log.e(TAG, "Record count::" + sz_RecordCount);

            loadmoreData();


        } else {
            CSnackBar.getInstance().showSnackBarError(m_MainLayout, "No internet connection available", getActivity());
            m_ListView.removeFooterView(mFooter);
        }

    }
}

@SuppressLint("InflateParams")
@Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

    bBottomOfView = (firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount) == totalItemCount;
    if (m_ListView.getFooterViewsCount() == 0) {
        mFooter = ((LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.footer, null, false);
        m_ListView.addFooterView(mFooter);

    }

}
```

Comment: Use a `boolean` flag to lock until you loaded your data.

Comment: sample code plsss

Comment: I want without lockinh